# Bower (bower_components) item missing in browser but present on server

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm trying to debug a really bizarre issue. As part of the build process on a project I'm working on, a *bower_components* folder is created with all the packages listed in the bower.json file. This process seems to complete successfully. However, when I refresh the project and view it in the browser, there is a single missing package (in this specific case it is angular-ui-sortable). The package is present in bower_components directory on the server, but absent when viewing that same directory in Chrome devtools. The missing package is breaking the UI since Angular throws an "$injector error" because it is unable to find the missing package. The question I have is, how do i even begin to debug this issue. I've confirmed that I'm looking at the correct folder as well as checked the missing package's permissions. I've also confirmed that the package is correctly included in the project's index.html file.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "absent when viewing that same directory in Chrome devtools"? Do you mean on the "sources" tab? It sounds like your reference to the file in index.html is incorrect. If you check the "network" tab during initial page load, do you get a 404 for the file(s) being referenced?

Comment: You're exactly right. There was a discrepancy between the reference in the index.html file and the package structure, causing the problem. Thanks for your help.